# Exclude record if duplicate record has certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of users who have certain roles. A user is entered into the table one time for each role they have. I need to get a count of all users who have certain roles but I need to exclude any duplicate record that also has another role. Below is what is populated in my table

```
Name   Role
Steve  ROLE_8
Steve  ROLE_9
Steve  ROLE_1
```

And this is the query I have to select users who have certain roles. What I need to do is check to see if a user has ROLE_1 but also check if there is another instance of that user who has a role that I do not wish to include and exclude that user from the return set.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.user_id)
FROM users c
WHERE email_addr != ''
AND email_addr IS NOT NULL
AND EXISTS
(SELECT r.role_id
 FROM ROLE r, user_role ur
 WHERE c.user_id = ur.user_id
   AND ur.role_id = r.role_id
   AND (r.name = 'ROLE_1'
        OR r.name = 'ROLE_2'
        OR r.name = 'ROLE_3'
        OR r.name = 'ROLE_4'
        OR r.name = 'ROLE_5'
        OR r.name = 'ROLE_6'))
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the output that you want?

Comment: If I'm searching for only users with roles 1 through 6 and a user has two records in the database, one with ROLE_1 and one with ROLE_8 then I want to exclude that user altogether from the return set. So in the example I gave I would want to return 0 records but because each record has a unique role I am getting 1 (because I'm choosing distinct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `DISTINCT` in your `COUNT` makes the `EXISTS` unnecessary - you can just join to the `user_role` table. At that point you just need to exclude those users who also have one of the roles that you don't want:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT U.user_id)
FROM
    Users U
INNER JOIN User_Role UR ON UR.user_id = U.user_id AND
INNER JOIN Role R ON
    R.role_id = UR.role_id AND
    R.name IN ('ROLE_USER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_1'...)
WHERE
    U.email_addr IS NOT NULL AND U.email_addr <> '' AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            User_Role UR2
        INNER JOIN Role R2 ON
            R2.role_id = UR2.role_id AND
            R2.name IN ('Some_Excluded_Role')
        WHERE
            UR2.user_id = U.user_id
    )
```

If you want to exclude any user who has **any** role outside of your list then you can do the following:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT U.user_id)
FROM
    Users U
INNER JOIN User_Role UR ON UR.user_id = U.user_id AND
INNER JOIN Role R ON
    R.role_id = UR.role_id AND
    R.name IN ('ROLE_USER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_1'...)
WHERE
    U.email_addr IS NOT NULL AND U.email_addr <> '' AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            User_Role UR2
        INNER JOIN Role R2 ON
            R2.role_id = UR2.role_id AND
            R2.name NOT IN ('ROLE_USER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_1'...)
        WHERE
            UR2.user_id = U.user_id
    )
```

Comment: Marking this as correct because it was the first answer I tested with and it both examples gave me the expected results. Thanks so much! If I should expand on my question for future readers let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will get you what you're looking for (without knowing exactly what you expect the results to look like). The concept being to first find the ones that match the 'good' roles and then filter with the other sub-select the ones that also have 'bad' roles.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.[user_id])
FROM users AS c
    INNER JOIN user_role AS ur
        ON ur.[user_id] = c.[user_id]
WHERE c.email_addr != ''
    AND c.email_addr IS NOT NULL
    AND ur.role_id IN 
        (SELECT sub_r.role_id
        FROM [role] AS sub_r
        WHERE sub_r.name IN ('ROLE_USER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_1')
        )
    AND c.[user_id] NOT IN 
        (SELECT sub2_ur.[user_id]
        FROM user_role AS sub2_ur
            INNER JOIN [role] AS sub2_r
                ON sub2_r.role_id = sub2_ur.role_id
        WHERE sub2_r.name IN ('ROLE_NOT_TO_USE','ANOTHER_NOT_TO_USE')
            AND sub2_ur.[user_id] = c.[user_id]
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to get a dataset in which I'm including users that have either role 1, 2, or 3 and I wanted to exclude users that had role 4 and 5, I would do the following, if "Name" is unique:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name)
FROM ROLE
WHERE Role IN ('ROLE_1','ROLE_2','ROLE_3')
AND Name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM ROLE WHERE Role IN ('ROLE_4','ROLE_5');
```